# Does Code Coverage support DART 2 for Flutter projects?

Tags: flutter, dart, code-coverage

On the Official Flutter Packages website, it is written that the plugin for Code Coverage, **dart_codecov_generator** (https://pub.dev/packages/dart_codecov_generator), is **DART 2 INCOMPATIBLE**. So, is there a way we can use Code Coverage for Flutter projects?

Answer (score 2):

Yes it possible to get the code coverage for a flutter project.

if you run `flutter test --coverage`, it will output a file (lcov.info) in the coverage folder and then multiple solution are possible:

- you can use `genhtml` program on this file to get the coverage (you will have to do some parsing)
- use online tool like codecov to upload you code coverage into the service.

Comment: After running `flutter test --coverage` it is producing an empty **lcov.info** file. How to fix this?

Comment: You can also use the `--coverage-path` option, e.g.: `flutter test --coverage --coverage-path=path/lcov.info`.