# Code Coverage Visualization for Dart/Flutter (Specially for Windows and VS Code)

Tags: flutter, dart, visual-studio-code, command-line-interface, code-coverage

> This was originally a [Github Issue in the Dart-Code repository](https://github.com/Dart-Code/Dart-Code/issues/2860).

### 1. Context

I've been working on a package that has hundreds of tests, so an easy way of visualizing code coverage would be incredibly handy.

I would like to run my tests with, say, a `.vscode` configuration with an `lcov.info` output which would automatically be recognized by VS Code and highlighted on the respective editors with either red or green.

### 2. What I've Already Tried

I've tried many different solutions in the past few days — months actually — but none of them worked as the ideal one described above:

- `flutter test --coverage --coverage-path=lcov.info` does work to generate the necessary file, but it's clunky to have to visualize it through a 3rd party program such as `genhtml`, all the more if you're on Windows.

  - And it does need Flutter in the end, which should not be necessary if you're working on pure Dart...
- IntelliJ would supposedly work ideally, but I just can't seem to enable the <kbd>Run with Coverage</kbd> button on mine, even after installing the [`test_coverage`](https://pub.dev/packages/test_coverage) package.

  - Though one person on Gitter told me he has it working on his IntelliJ.
- Both the [`coverage`](https://pub.dev/packages/coverage) and the [`test_coverage`](https://pub.dev/packages/test_coverage) packages offer something close to what I described above, but their solutions are way clunkier — and on Windows they are tough to set up...
- [codecov.io](https://codecov.io) is an alternative with a 3rd party, but it's annoying to have to handle this externally when the editor offers a much more flexible and faster experience.

  - And there is also the problem of ambiguous coverage, which is not clear with respect to [codecov.io](https://codecov.io). For example, if one folder tests stuff that indirectly calls another folder, does that count as coverage for the indirectly called folder as well? That's almost always undesirable.

### 3. Other Resources

1. There's [this old question on StackOverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/q/57676707/4756173) that was helpful initially.

Comment: you linked `3.` to this question, that is recursion

Comment: Nicely spotted!

Answer (score 2):

1. You can take the `genhtml.perl` script [here](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/valbok/lcov/master/genhtml.perl).
2. If you have Git for Windows installed on your machine, you already have Perl installed, it should be here: `<git-install-dir>\usr\bin\perl.exe`
3. Replace backslash characters (`\\`) with slash characters (`/`) in all file path lines (prefixed with `SF:`) in the `lcov.info` file.
4. Run `genhtml.perl` script. For example — assumed current working directory is root directory of your project —:

   ```sh
   <git-install-dir>\usr\bin\perl.exe \
       C:\Scripts\genhtml.perl \
       -o .\coverage\html .\coverage\lcov.info
   ```

   Note. It may be useful also to add the `--prefix` option.

As a result of these actions, you should get generated HTML report in the `.\coverage\html/` directory. Open `.\coverage\html\index.html` file in your browser to see the report.

I hope this helps — at least, it worked for me.

Comment: I'll see if I can try this. Thanks for the answer.

Comment: if I keep the file as it was, the command ran but resulted in 0 lines covered. If I replace ````\````  with ``/`` I get cannot read file.